# Shorter links to questions

Tags: support, links

I noticed that I can use

```
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1
```

as a link to a question rather than the longer

```
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1/chewy-chocolate-chips-cookies
```

Is this supported or is this some unexpected “feature?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's supported. You can also use

[How can I get chewy chocolate chip cookies?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1)